# Add Clarification When Updating Profile Picture

Tags: feature-request, profile-picture

**Note:** This question was originally me listing what I thought was a "bug". That is, I tried to update my profile picture multiple times and wasn't sure why it wasn't working without any feedback.

[Rizier123](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123) kindly informed me in the comments below that it wasn't a bug at all - but rather I just wasn't pressing the "SAVE" button.

---

I personally believe the main source of confusion is that your updated, *un-saved* profile picture displays **outside of the *"Edit Profile & Settings"* form**.

In the image below, I updated my profile image and *didn't save*. But the image on the top right, which appears outside of the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab, reflects my update:

[image]

It seems intuitive (as someone who does a bit of UI/UX myself) that everything within the form is temporary until saved. However, by showing the new image *outside* of the form, it removes it from the area of unsaved changes; it implies the change was committed.

Comment: You hit the "save profile" button all the way at the bottom of the page, right? :)

Comment: @Rizier123 ...what's the best household cleaner to remove embarrassment?

Comment: Happened to me too once, so you're not alone.

Comment: @Rizier123 On a real note: Should I delete this question? Or does this seem like something people do often enough that maybe it should warrant a discussion of some sort? It just seems counter-intuitive to show the successful image update without any mention. My initial thought was that the uploader was an entirely separate control.

Comment: You can probably delete the question if you want and don't see any value in it, but it's up to you.

Comment: @Rizier123 Changed the question to instead be discussion based. Not sure if you want to remove or leave the comments here, now that they don't seem entirely relevant anymore.

Comment: It's not completely obvious but if you look at the top nav bar your avatar does not change there after you change the avatar but before you save it.  That should indicate that change hasn't actually been applied.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes I realize that now, though I still personally believe that does little to reduce the confusion. It reflects the change outside of the form in one place, but not in another. I think that if the change was not reflected outside the form *at all*, it would be entirely more clear. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Santi I Agree with you there.  I think they should just get rid of the avatar in the top right corner.

Comment: They should just get rid of avatars entirely... *drops mic*

Comment: Literally took me about a week to change my profile picture from that default pattern because I didn't realise you had to click save...

Comment: A warning when navigating away might be in order "You have unsaved changes to your profile..."